# Angularjs Routing want it to work

Tags: angular-routing

I know that there are many example for angularjs routing but don't know why this is not working for me. I have trying to do one by myself. Below is plunk I am using please point me where I am going wrong... What I am missing because it is not working on my system.

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/AK32mYeV41F2AlFBUFMB?p=preview)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.21"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.2.17" data-semver="1.2.17" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
        <h1>My app</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                template: '<h2>{{page}}</h2>',
                controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
                    $scope.page = 'home';
                }]
            })
            .when('/about', {
                template: '<h2>{{page}}</h2>',
                controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
                    $scope.page = 'about';
                }]
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing `https` in angular-route.js

use this `src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular-route.js"`

Following was the error in console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/AK32mYeV41F2AlFBUFMB?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular-route.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Hi Pranav, Thanks, that helped I also had the do the same change for angular-route reference